# I need to implement Asp.net Web API 2 and consume it by Sencha Ext JS

Tags: extjs, asp.net-web-api2

I want to implement a web-based API (using ASP.NET Web API 2) and consume it by  the client Side library (Sencha Ext JS).

My application should include

1. A simple user registration form.
2. A login page for admin.
3. CRUD operations for users' submissions.

Notes:

- I do not want to include any backend code (i.e C#) in the we application, I want to implement it using the HTML/Javascript only, that is Ext JS.
- I want the Web API to be RESTful.
- I want to protect admin pages.
- I want to use the SQL Server to store users' submissions.

All of that requirements should be implemented using the ASP.net Web API 2 and Ext JS only.

So far, I did initial search and I got a lot of learning for either the ASP.net API 2 or the Ext JS. But I couldn't have a guide that help me to fulfill the above requirements or help me to have both technologies work together.
Pleas help me on either way.

Or generally, can you help me get started work in combining both: Asp.net Web API 2 and any client side that consumes it, such as Sencha Ext JS or any other client side. It is not necessarily to be Ext JS.

Thank you so much. 
Thanks to StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd use the DirectAPI for asp.net https://github.com/elishnevsky/ext-direct-mvc

You create webapi controllers, just like you normally would.  The only difference is the the controllers that need to be used by EXT should inherit from DirectController.

If you follow the directions on that page, you'll end up with a globally available proxy object that matches the name of the controller and the public methods hanging off of the controller become methods of that object.

That is, server side controller MyAwesomeController with method DoSomething() becomes MyAwesome.DoSomething.

If you attribute the method as [NamedArguements] you can create methods such as

DoSomething(int id, int foo)

and pass from javascript as DoSomething({id: 20, foo: 30});

Since it is still just a controller, you can attribute permissions and return json as you would in any other situation.

If you get stuck, use the debugger and spend the time to figure out what's really going on.  This all works in 4.x and I've tried it in 5.x and it still works there as well.  But I wouldn't jump into 5.x just yet as there are still several bugs that need to be worked out by the sencha team before it is ready for prime time.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJs has a REST proxy for the data. So what you try to do should be possible. The proxy can be configured and be finetuned.

I used the JSON proxy. ExtJs has very powerful filter and sort capabilities, both server and client side. In my experience difficulties arose when filtering and sorting server side. There is only sparse documentation on how the parameters are passed and which configurations have what effects.

Since you also develop the REST api, you can adapt to those details. You just have to do some research.

Here is not the place to ask about guides. For Asp I cannot help you, I never touched it. If you use ExtJs, you are free to choose you backend. For ExtJs, the start is pretty straight forward :

- get Sencha cmd and generate a skeleton app.
- follow the tutorial
- create one file per class definition.
- the API docs are great. If you still lack something SO is great too.
- what you have to find out by yourself is the exact way parameters are passed to the backend and how to format the response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can I have guide how to start working in both techniques? Asp.net We API 2 and ExtJS ? Or, Asp.net Web API 2 with any other client side library. I am a beginner.